# Output single line of multi-line CimInstance

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to find a full solution to capture information from with `Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter` and save it to a table on a server. Currently I am using the code around below:

```
$SerialNum = Get-CIMInstance WIN32_BIOS | SELECT -ExpandProperty SerialNumber 
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter | Select-Object * |
 Export-Csv S:\$SerialNum-NetAdptr.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
  Import-Csv S:\$SerialNum-NetAdptr.csv |
   Select-Object *, @{Name='Serial';Expression={Get-CIMInstance WIN32_BIOS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber}} |
    Export-Csv S:\$SerialNum-NetAdptrSerialized.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
     Remove-Item S:\$SerialNum-NetAdptr.csv
```

The issue I am having is computers with multiple NICs output multiple lines so outputting like:

```
$NetAdptrINF = Get-CIMInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter | Select-Object *
$objRecordSet.Fields.Item("ProductName").Value = ($NetAdptrINF.ProductName).ToString()
```

or

```
$objRecordSet.Fields.Item("ProductName").Value = $NetAdptrINF.ProductName
```

Saves something along the lines of: `System[].object` in the field. I have been looking at using foreach to print one line of each network adapter property at a time but have been unable to get anything that even remotely works. I am using PowerShell bundled in Windows 10 ADK.

`$NetAdptrInf.ProductName` outputs:

`Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter`

I need to be able to output one `ProductName` save it to a record along with other information collected from Win32_NetworkAdapter then move to the next one and repeat.

Thank you.

Comment: What format *do* you expect the multple NICs in? A comma separated list per computer?

Comment: what is $NetAdptrINF equal to? please provide the assignment code for that variable. and maybe the output of $NetAdptrINF.ProductName to the console

Answer (score 0):

According the fact that `$NetAdptrINF` is evaluated as follow :

```
$NetAdptrINF = Get-CIMInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter
```

You can use the following to retreive a text list of product names :

```
($NetAdptrINF | % { $_.productname}) -join ','
```

---

Edited :

If you want to get a reccord by productname :

```
Get-CIMInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter | Select-Object DeviceId,Name,Productname,ServiceName,AdapterType
```

Comment: This would help exporting a CSV file however to send the information directly to records in a database table I currently need to be able to pull one product name at a time.